# How can I edit hovertext labels in Plotly Python?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, plotly, heatmap

When I'm hovering on a plot in Heatmap it is showing axis as x, y, z.

But I wanted it to be like Year, Month, No. of Passengers respectively

Heatmap:
[image: See the image of Heatmap here]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

flights_data_csv = pd.read_csv("flights.csv")

data = [go.Heatmap(x=flights_data_csv["year"],
                   y=flights_data_csv["month"],
                   z=flights_data_csv["passengers"].values.tolist(),
                   colorbar=dict(title="Passengers traveled <br>by Flights"),
                   colorscale="jet",
                   zmin=100,
                   zmax=650)]

layout = go.Layout(title="Exercise of HeatMaps <br>For Showing Flights details",
                   title_x=0.5)
fig = go.Figure(data, layout)
pyo.plot(fig, filename="Flights Heatmaps.html")
```

[Here is flight dataset](https://github.com/AmanRathoreM/All-in-Python/blob/main/Tutorials/Python%20Modules/Plotly/Part%203%20(Plotly%20Basics)/flights.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [hovertemplate](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-text-with-a-hovertemplate) and specify the format:

```
Year:%{x}<br>Month:%{y}<br>Passengers:%{z}
```

Variables are referenced by `%{x}`, `%{y}`, and `%{z}` respectively, otherwise html can be used to format the display.

```
data = [
    go.Heatmap(x=flights_data_csv["year"],
               y=flights_data_csv["month"],
               z=flights_data_csv["passengers"],
               colorbar=dict(title="Passengers traveled <br>by Flights"),
               colorscale="jet",
               zmin=100,
               zmax=650,
               hovertemplate='Year:%{x}<br>Month:%{y}<br>Passengers:%{z}',
               name='')
]
```

[image: hover text]

`name` is set to the empty string (`name=''`), otherwise `trace 0` will appear as the label:

[image: hover text with name]